# "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server" error while trying to send email though django app using gmail

Tags: django, smtp

I am trying to send a mail from my django application  through gmail and i get the error saying "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server."

I have added

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USER_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abc@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'random'
```

in my setting.py.
Can anyone please help me figure out the solution?

Answer (score 1):

**`EMAIL_USER_TLS` IS WRONG**.

Use [`EMAIL_USE_TLS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#s-std:setting-EMAIL_USE_TLS) instead (fix typing error).

Gmail offers SMTP `AUTH` on port 587 **only after STARTTLS**.
Without `STARTTLS` (turning on encryption) SMTP `AUTH` is unavailable.

Comment: Thank you really appreciate the help.:)